# Dataframe to count conditional occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A data frame like below.

[image]

I want to find out when sales was >20, (in its previous 5 data) how many times the inventory was > 10.

The ideal output is:

```
2018/12/26 has Sales 36 when 2 times.
2018/11/19 has Sales 34 when 2 times.
```

Here is what I do with xlrd:

```
import xlrd
from datetime import datetime

old_file = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Sales.xlsx")
the_sheet = old_file.sheet_by_name("Sales")

for row_index in range(1, the_sheet.nrows):
    Dates = the_sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value
    Inventory = the_sheet.cell(row_index, 1).value
    Sales = the_sheet.cell(row_index, 2).value

    list_of_Inventory = []

    for i in range(1,5):
        list_of_Inventory.append(the_sheet.cell(row_index - i, 1).value)

    if Sales > 20:
        print str(Dates) + " has Sales " + str(Sales) + " when " + str(sum(i > 10 for i in list_of_Inventory)) + " times."
```

It doesn't work well.

What would be the proper way to work it out? Appreciate some guidance in pandas.

Thank you.

p.s. here is the data.

```
data = {'Date':     ["2018/12/29","2018/12/26","2018/12/24","2018/12/15","2018/12/11","2018/12/8","2018/11/28","2018/11/20","2018/11/19","2018/11/11","2018/11/6","2018/11/1","2018/10/28","2018/10/11","2018/9/25","2018/9/24"], 
'Inventory': [5,5,5,22,5,25,5,15,15,5,5,15,0,22,2,10],
'Sales' : [0,36,18,0,0,17,18,17,34,16,0,0,18,18,51,18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Just one note - you don't mean"previous" data, you mean "afterwards" data (both by date and by rows order), right?

Comment: @Grzegorz Skibinski, thank you for pointing out the mistake in the question. Yes, it should be earlier in date history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to get around iterating over the dataframe (based on the specifics of your output).  So provided your data isn't huge, it shouldn't be a problem.  Here's another quick solution you can implement:

```
for idx in df.loc[df.Sales > 20].index:
    inv = df.loc[idx-4:idx, 'Inventory'].ge(10)
    date, _, sales = df.loc[idx]
    if len(inv) >= 5:
        print(f'{date} has Sales {sales} when {inv.sum()} times')

2018/11/19 has Sales 34 when 2 times
2018/9/25 has Sales 51 when 2 times
```

Comment: thank you for the help. but it gives "SyntaxError: invalid syntax
" on this line "print (f'{date} has Sales {sales} when {inv.sum()} times')".

Comment: You likely don't have Python 3.6 or later installed.  You can always use the string format method instead of f strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get there with a couple of "cheater" columns to do some intermediate work using pandas `rolling` function.  Note 'HSHIC' = High Sales High Inventory Count.  (Needed an acronym).  This actually works well for your desire to exclude first 4 rows because `rolling` will exclude them automatically.

```
In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                                 

In [43]: df                                                                      
Out[43]: 
          Date  Inventory  Sales
0   2018/12/29          5      0
1   2018/12/26          5     36
2   2018/12/24          5     18
3   2018/12/15          6      0
4   2018/12/11          5      0
5    2018/12/8          0     17
6   2018/11/28          5     18
7   2018/11/20         15     17
8   2018/11/19         15     34
9   2018/11/11          5     16
10   2018/11/6          5      0
11   2018/11/1         15      0
12  2018/10/28          0     18
13  2018/10/11         10     18
14   2018/9/25          2     51
15   2018/9/24         10     18

In [44]: df['High Inventory'] = df['Inventory'] > 10                             

In [45]: df['High Inv Cnt'] = df['High Inventory'].rolling(window=5).sum()       

In [46]: df                                                                      
Out[46]: 
          Date  Inventory  Sales  High Inventory  High Inv Cnt
0   2018/12/29          5      0           False           NaN
1   2018/12/26          5     36           False           NaN
2   2018/12/24          5     18           False           NaN
3   2018/12/15          6      0           False           NaN
4   2018/12/11          5      0           False           0.0
5    2018/12/8          0     17           False           0.0
6   2018/11/28          5     18           False           0.0
7   2018/11/20         15     17            True           1.0
8   2018/11/19         15     34            True           2.0
9   2018/11/11          5     16           False           2.0
10   2018/11/6          5      0           False           2.0
11   2018/11/1         15      0            True           3.0
12  2018/10/28          0     18           False           2.0
13  2018/10/11         10     18           False           1.0
14   2018/9/25          2     51           False           1.0
15   2018/9/24         10     18           False           1.0

In [47]: df['HSHIC'] = df['High Inv Cnt'][df.Sales > 20]                         

In [48]: df                                                                      
Out[48]: 
          Date  Inventory  Sales  High Inventory  High Inv Cnt  HSHIC
0   2018/12/29          5      0           False           NaN    NaN
1   2018/12/26          5     36           False           NaN    NaN
2   2018/12/24          5     18           False           NaN    NaN
3   2018/12/15          6      0           False           NaN    NaN
4   2018/12/11          5      0           False           0.0    NaN
5    2018/12/8          0     17           False           0.0    NaN
6   2018/11/28          5     18           False           0.0    NaN
7   2018/11/20         15     17            True           1.0    NaN
8   2018/11/19         15     34            True           2.0    2.0
9   2018/11/11          5     16           False           2.0    NaN
10   2018/11/6          5      0           False           2.0    NaN
11   2018/11/1         15      0            True           3.0    NaN
12  2018/10/28          0     18           False           2.0    NaN
13  2018/10/11         10     18           False           1.0    NaN
14   2018/9/25          2     51           False           1.0    1.0
15   2018/9/24         10     18           False           1.0    NaN

In [49]:
```

Comment: thank you for the help. is there a way to print the wanted output as 2 lines of texts?

Answer (score 0):

Error in the first post of the question (what's on page now is correct), so let me put down a working solution by Python 2.

Thanks to @manwithfewneeds and @kantal.

```
for idx in df.index[df.Sales > 20]:
    inv = df.loc[idx + 1 : idx + 5, 'Inventory'].ge(10)   # downwards 5 rows, Inventory > 10
    date, _, sales = df.loc[idx]
    if len(inv) >= 5:
        print '%s. has Sales %s. when %s. times' % (date, sales, inv.sum())
```